# How to iterate over columns with string values using get-dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables

I have a dataframe with 45 columns. Most are string values, so I'm trying to use pd.get_dummies to turn the strings into numbers using df = pd.get_dummies(drop_first=True); however, the columns without string values are removed from my dataframe. I don't want to have to type out 40 or so columns names. How can I iterate over every column, ignoring ones without strings and still have them remain after the get_dummies call?

Comment: It's a good idea to add some sample data and expected output while asking the quesetion.

Answer (score 0):

Columns can be filtered by [`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to programmatically determine which columns to pass to [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), namely only the "object or category" type columns:

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(
    df,
    columns=df.columns[(df.dtypes == 'object') | (df.dtypes == 'category')]
)
```

---

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 100, n),
    'B': pd.Series(np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), n), dtype='category'),
    'C': np.random.random(n) * 100,
    'D': np.random.choice(list("EFGH"), n)
})

new_df = pd.get_dummies(
    df,
    columns=df.columns[(df.dtypes == 'object') | (df.dtypes == 'category')]
)
```

`df`:

```
    A  B          C  D
0  79  A  76.437261  G
1  62  D  11.090076  E
2  17  B  20.415475  E
3  74  B  11.909536  E
4   9  D  87.790307  G
5  63  A  52.367529  E
6  28  D  49.213600  F
7  31  A  73.187110  H
8  81  B   1.458075  H
9   8  D   9.336303  H
```

`df.dtypes`:

```
A       int32
B    category
C     float64
D      object
dtype: object
```

`new_df`:

```
    A          C  B_A  B_B  B_D  D_E  D_F  D_G  D_H
0  79  76.437261    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
1  62  11.090076    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
2  17  20.415475    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
3  74  11.909536    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
4   9  87.790307    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
5  63  52.367529    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
6  28  49.213600    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
7  31  73.187110    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
8  81   1.458075    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
9   8   9.336303    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
```